# Async/await and resource access

Tags: c#, async-await

I’m wondering how to implement resource access nicely using async/await. I have singleton service in web application that is acting as a proxy to LDAP and have to buffer all data on first access – all invocation after that is done via cache but after some time cache is invalidated and data should be get again. Now my implementation looks like this but it is not meet my requirements

```
public async Task<string> GetUserDisplayName(string username)
       {
           var users = await GetCachedUsers();

           // code using users from cache
       }

private async Task<IEnumerable<LdapUser>> GetCachedUsers()
{
     var users = _Cache.Get<IEnumerable<LdapUser>>();

     if (users == null)
     {
         users = await _Connector.GetAllUsers();

         _Cache.Add(users, TimeSpan.FromHours(USER_CACHE_VALID_HOURS));
     }


    return users;
}
```

I’m wondering how to implement this in this way that when couple request go to the service first time they should be awaited on the same task but not blocked and download from LDAP should go only once. I could do this traditionally and lock the resource but that threads will be blocked and I want them to back to threadpool in async way like in async/wait pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SemaphoreSlim` has a `WaitAsync` method that will let you create a critical section in asynchronous code.  You can use that semaphore to prevent multiple invocations of the method from generating the value together without actually blocking any of the threads.